# Trying to add a new row dynamically to a UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView in my app to which I am trying to dynamically add rows to, by clicking a button.  When the user clicks my button, the following method is called:

```
- (IBAction)addChoice:(id)sender {
    //addRow is a boolean variable that is set so that we can use it to check later and add a new row
    if (!self.addRow) {
        self.addRow = YES;
    }

    [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```

which then calls:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.choiceTable setEditing:editing animated:animated];

}
```

The problem, is that neither of the following delegate methods that I have implemented are being called, despite my having implemented UITableViewDelegate, and UITableViewDataSource:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (self.addRow) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSArray *indexPathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [self.tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSArray *indexPathArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        NSString *theObjectToInsert = @"New Row";
        [self.tableData addObject:theObjectToInsert];
        [tableView reloadData];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }   
}
```

Can anyone see what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes. If you want to add a row, simply add an element to your underlying array of whatever is driving your table view and call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`. The delegate methods you have shown are for responding to edit events initiated by your user

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt reply.  What then should be the parameter that I pass insertRowsAtIndexPaths for the indexPaths?

Comment: The index path of the new row, which assuming you are adding to the end of the array will be `array.count-1`

Comment: The array that I have which holds my data is self.tableData, and the method is expecting an array.  So would my method call be: [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:self.tableData withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
 ?  I apologize for being stupid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to insert an additional row into your table data array and then call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` on your tableview to let the table view know about the new row.  The new row will be at the end of the array, so row count-1.

```
[self.tableData addObject:newObject];
NSIndexPath *newPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.tableData.count-1 inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should perform insertion or deletion on the `UITableView` like this :

```
[tableView beginUpdates];

// Add object to the array
[self.tableData addObject:theObjectToInsert];

// perform tableView insertion/delete here
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Ideally it should be where you inserted the object in your array, here in this case it should be `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.tableData count]-1 inSection:0]`.

Comment: `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.tableData indexOfObject:theObjectToInsert] inSection:0]`